# Ulm Invariants of a reduced abelian primary group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, p-groups, infinite-groups

> Let $G$ be a reduced abelian primary group of lenght $\lambda$, and let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $\beta$ a limit ordinal and $\alpha < \beta \leq \lambda$. Show that the Ulm Invariants of $G_{\alpha}/G_{\beta}$ coincide with the Ulm Invariants of $G$ between $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Question 35 from the book *Infinite Abelian Groups* by Irving Kaplansky, 1971 (second edition).

Definition$_0$: A group $G$ is *divisible* if for all $x\in G$ and all $n\in N$ there exists an $y \in G$ such that $x=ny$. If the only element that satisfies this property in $G$ is $0$ we call $G$ *reduced*.

A group $G$ is *primary* if for all $g\in G$ there exists an $n \in N$ such that $o(g)=p^n$ and $p$ is a prime number.

Definition$_1$: Let $G$ be a primary abelian group we define:

(i) $G_n=p^n G$

(ii) $G_{\omega}=\cap_{i\in N}G_n$

(iii) $G_{\omega+1}=pG_{\omega}$

(iv) If $\beta$ is a limit ordinal we define $G_{\beta}=\cap_{\alpha < \beta}G_{\alpha}$ (the intersection of all $\alpha<\beta$ where $\alpha$ is an ordinal), and $G_{\beta+1}=pG_{\beta}$.

(v) We define the group length $\lambda$ as the first ordinal such that $G_\lambda=G_{\lambda+1}$ (notice that this will be the maximal divisible part of the group, and if $G$ is reduced than $G_\lambda=0$).

Definition$_2$: Let $S$ be a subgroup of $G$, then we define $S_\alpha=G_\alpha \cap S$.

Definition (Ulm Invariants): Let $G$ be a group, we define $P=\{x\in G\mid px=0\}$. All the elements of $P$ have order $p$, so it's a vector space over $\mathbb F_p$. We define the $\alpha$-th *Ulm Invariant* of $G$ as the dimension of $P_\alpha/P_{\alpha+1}$ over $\mathbb F_p$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say what your thoughts on it are, and what you have tried to solve the problem; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: To your credit, 7jvps7, I appreciate the fact that you cited the source of the question.  Could you add a few words about where you are stuck, or what exactly you don't understand?

Comment: @amWhy The problem is that in this case I don't know how to begin

Comment: That can be okay to not know how to start, when you provide more context:e.g., given your notes and text, add how you define "Ulm invariants of a group" ...  explain what you know about what it means to be "a reduced abelian primary group of length $\lambda$."

Comment: I added the definitions of everything I am using, if this helps.

Comment: It might help to write $P(G) = \{x \in G : px = 0\}$, so then the $\alpha$-th Ulm invariant of $G$ is $P(G)_\alpha/P(G)_{\alpha+1}$. The exercise follows from the identities (i) $P(G_\alpha) = P(G)_\alpha$ for any ordinal $\alpha$, which is clear from the definitions, and (ii) $P(G/G_\beta) = P(G)/G_\beta$ for any limit ordinal $\beta$ with $\beta \le \lambda$, which you need to prove.